# AttributeError when importing google cloud big query library

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Today I tried to use my new computer to run the libraries I have been using at work, but I've encountered this error when I tried to import bigquery:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
from google.cloud import bigquery

~\anaconda3\envs\base\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\__init__.py in <module>
     33 __version__ = get_distribution("google-cloud-bigquery").version
     34 
---> 35 from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client
     36 from google.cloud.bigquery.dataset import AccessEntry
     37 from google.cloud.bigquery.dataset import Dataset
~\anaconda3\envs\base\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\client.py in <module>
     56 from google.cloud.bigquery._helpers import _verify_job_config_type
     57 from google.cloud.bigquery._http import Connection
---> 58 from google.cloud.bigquery import _pandas_helpers
     59 from google.cloud.bigquery.dataset import Dataset
     60 from google.cloud.bigquery.dataset import DatasetListItem
~\anaconda3\envs\base\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\_pandas_helpers.py in <module>
     38     pyarrow = None
     39 
---> 40 from google.cloud.bigquery import schema
     41 
     42 
~\anaconda3\envs\base\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\schema.py in <module>
     26 # https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types
     27 LEGACY_TO_STANDARD_TYPES = {
---> 28     "STRING": types.StandardSqlDataType.STRING,
     29     "BYTES": types.StandardSqlDataType.BYTES,
     30     "INTEGER": types.StandardSqlDataType.INT64,
AttributeError: type object 'StandardSqlDataType' has no attribute 'STRING'
```

I'm new to programming so I don't know where to start solving the problem. I tried googling but didn't find a similar question raised.

Comment: Checks the version of the libraries and python.

Comment: Try running "pip install google-cloud-bigquery" in your shell and then try importing again

Answer (score 0):

Run

```sh
python3 -m pip install -U google-cloud-bigquery
```